# Possible to compile-time check constructor parameters for generic factory function?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, compile-time

I am experimenting with some factory type code where the BuildIt function returns a concrete type based solely on the generic type passed in.  The generic type is restricted to being descendants of the BaseAbstract class.

The Buildit function just needs the generic type and then a list of params (the params are used as constructor parameters in the BuildIt function when creating the concrete classes).

The example code below works as expected (prints "A" then "B")

But the problem happens if I try to call something like:

```
        var b = fs.BuildIt<B>("B", "C");
```

Since the B class doesn't have a constructor with 2 parameters, this fails at runtime.

Is it possible to do something like this, except have this fail at compile time? If not, is there another way to go about this so that compile time checking is possible (doesn't matter if all this has to be thrown out and start something completely different)

**Example Code**

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public string Name ="";
    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class A : BaseAbstract
{
    public A()
    {
        Name = "A";
    }
}

public class B : BaseAbstract
{
    public B()
    {
    }

    public B(string param)
    {
        Name = param;
    }
}

public class Factory
{
    public T BuildIt<T>(params object[] args) where T : BaseAbstract, new()
    {
        T x = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
        return x;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        //These are fine
        Factory fs = new Factory();
        var a = fs.BuildIt<A>();
        var b = fs.BuildIt<B>("B");
        Console.WriteLine (a);
        Console.WriteLine (b);

          //This would cause runtime error because of the "C" paramter
          //var b2 = fs.BuildIt<B>("B", "C");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, since you're using reflection which is a runtime technology... The only way the compiler would become aware of the inability to create your instance would be to run your code... At least until the CAAS shows up.

One option might be to approach this differently: force a new() constraint on your generic type in the method (makes sure that all types have a parameterless constructor) and then maybe map the constructor parameters as properties instead on your types? Maybe not ideal if you want immutability but reflection can write to private types etc. anyway...

This is pretty much the kind of scenario that the **[ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** class was built for... Throw it if stuff doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about forcing new constraint. BuildIt already constrains on new().  Mapping to the properties instead is not bad, but I prefer to use the constructor as a guarantee that certain fields are populated. Would IoC container frameworks have this same limitation? Thanks for the input.

Comment: There are no IoC frameworks - IoC is a pattern/practice. There are DI frameworks which help with IoC such as Microsoft's Unity... However they are also runtime technologies (and that's their main feature - deferred execution/decision making of which class to resolve to runtime)... And they have the same issues: they barf at runtime and not compile time if the constructor arguments don't match.